# Dealing with periods and dates without using cursors

Tags: t-sql, date, fetch, cursors, period

I would like to solve this issue avoiding to use cursors (FETCH).

Here comes the problem...

```
1st Table/quantity
------------------
periodid periodstart periodend quantity

1        2010/10/01 2010/10/15    5


2st Table/sold items
-----------------------
periodid periodstart periodend solditems

14343    2010/10/05 2010/10/06    2
```

Now I would like to get the following view or just query result

```
Table Table/stock
-----------------------
periodstart periodend itemsinstock

2010/10/01 2010/10/04      5

2010/10/05 2010/10/06      3

2010/10/07 2010/10/15      5
```

It seems impossible to solve this problem without using cursors, or without using single dates instead of periods.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (periodid INT,periodstart DATE,periodend DATE,quantity INT)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (periodid INT,periodstart DATE,periodend DATE,solditems INT)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(1,'2010-10-01T00:00:00.000','2010-10-15T00:00:00.000',5)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(14343,'2010-10-05T00:00:00.000','2010-10-06T00:00:00.000',2)

DECLARE @D1 DATE

SELECT @D1 = MIN(P) FROM (SELECT MIN(periodstart) P FROM @t1
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT MIN(periodstart) FROM @t2) D

DECLARE @D2 DATE

SELECT @D2 = MAX(P) FROM (SELECT MAX(periodend) P FROM @t1
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT MAX(periodend) FROM @t2) D

;WITH 
L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS i FROM L4),
Dates AS(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,i-1,@D1) AS D FROM Nums where i <= 1+DATEDIFF(DAY,@D1,@D2))  , 
Stock As (
SELECT D ,t1.quantity - ISNULL(t2.solditems,0) AS itemsinstock
FROM Dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t1 t1 ON t1.periodend >= D and t1.periodstart <= D
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.periodend >= D and t2.periodstart <= D ),
NStock As (
select D,itemsinstock, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by D) - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by itemsinstock order by D) AS G
from Stock)
SELECT MIN(D) AS periodstart, MAX(D) AS periodend, itemsinstock 
FROM NStock
GROUP BY G, itemsinstock
ORDER BY periodstart
```

Comment: +1, works for me (after I changed all the `DATE` data types into `DATETIME` because I'm not on SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully a little easier to read than Martin's. I used different tables and sample data, hopefully extrapolating the right info:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quantity](
    [PeriodStart] [date] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodEnd] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SoldItems](
    [PeriodStart] [date] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodEnd] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SoldItems] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Quantity (PeriodStart,PeriodEnd,Quantity)
SELECT '20100101','20100115',5

INSERT INTO SoldItems (PeriodStart,PeriodEnd,SoldItems)
SELECT '20100105','20100107',2 union all
SELECT '20100106','20100108',1
```

The actual query is now:

```
;WITH Dates as (
    select PeriodStart as DateVal from SoldItems union select PeriodEnd from SoldItems union select PeriodStart from Quantity union select PeriodEnd from Quantity
), Periods as (
    select d1.DateVal as StartDate, d2.DateVal as EndDate
    from Dates d1 inner join Dates d2 on d1.DateVal < d2.DateVal left join Dates d3 on d1.DateVal < d3.DateVal and d3.DateVal < d2.DateVal where d3.DateVal is null
), QuantitiesSold as (
    select StartDate,EndDate,COALESCE(SUM(si.SoldItems),0) as Quantity
    from Periods p left join SoldItems si on p.StartDate < si.PeriodEnd and si.PeriodStart < p.EndDate
    group by StartDate,EndDate
)
select StartDate,EndDate,q.Quantity - qs.Quantity
from QuantitiesSold qs inner join Quantity q on qs.StartDate < q.PeriodEnd and q.PeriodStart < qs.EndDate
```

And the result is:

```
StartDate   EndDate (No column name)
2010-01-01  2010-01-05  5
2010-01-05  2010-01-06  3
2010-01-06  2010-01-07  2
2010-01-07  2010-01-08  4
2010-01-08  2010-01-15  5
```

Explanation: I'm using three Common Table Expressions. The first (Dates) is gathering all of the dates that we're talking about, from the two tables involved. The second (Periods) selects consecutive values from the Dates CTE. And the third (QuantitiesSold) then finds items in the SoldItems table that overlap these periods, and adds their totals together. All that remains in the outer select is to subtract these quantities from the total quantity stored in the Quantity Table

Comment: Yep - what we're missing at the moment (because the sample data isn't very expansive) is a) whether we have multiple rows in the quantities table (simple change to third CTE to accomodate), and whether there's an actual relationship between these two tables that isn't shown (e.g. more than one product being tracked)

Comment: @Martin - mine doesn't exactly match the OPs requirements, since my periods fully cover the ranges (i.e. my first period ends on 5th, not the 4th). That's because I'm used to modelling periods as [StartDate,EndDate) (a semi open interval)

Answer (score 0):

John, what you could do is a WHILE loop. Declare and initialise 2 variables before your loop, one being the start date and the other being end date. Your loop would then look like this:

```
WHILE(@StartEnd <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
  --processing goes here
  SET @StartEnd = @StartEnd + 1
END
```

You would need to store your period definitions in another table, so you could retrieve those and output rows when required to a temporary table.

Let me know if you need any more detailed examples, or if I've got the wrong end of the stick!

Comment: See this MSDN article for detailed usage of WHILE loops in T-SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx (assuming you're using SQL Server!)

Answer (score 0):

Damien,

I am trying to fully understand your solution and test it on a large scale of data, but I receive following errors for your code.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20

Incorrect syntax near 'Dates'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22

Incorrect syntax near ','.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25

Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: you'd have been better adding this as a comment to my answer, or editing it into your question (comment on my answer would have alerted me to your update).

Comment: only works with SQL 2005 or later (not sure which version you're on), and if the query is starting later in the batch, you need a ";" before the WITH keyword.

Comment: I am using SQL 2005 and already tried with ";" before the WITH kwd but always get the same set of errors. Since I do not use WITH that often, I tried to run some basic examples for WITH statement, and they have all return the same error. ??

Comment: Your solution works good using multiple rows in Quantitiy table. But it seems the problem with overlapping dates cannot be resolved using your solution. On the other hand, making necessary changes to adjust EndDate from 5th to 4th, would cause a single date period in SoldItems to be represented as for example 2010-05-05 - 2010-05-05. So, I believe this is a good solution for a data tier.

Answer (score 0):

Damien,

Based on your solution I also wanted to get a neat display for StockItems without overlapping dates. How about this solution?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SoldItems](
    [PeriodStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PeriodEnd] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SoldItems] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO SoldItems (PeriodStart,PeriodEnd,SoldItems)
SELECT '20100105','20100106',2 union all
SELECT '20100105','20100108',3 union all
SELECT '20100115','20100116',1 union all
SELECT '20100101','20100120',10


;WITH Dates as (
    select PeriodStart as DateVal from SoldItems
    union 
    select PeriodEnd from SoldItems 
    union
    select PeriodStart from Quantity
    union
    select PeriodEnd from Quantity

), Periods as (
    select d1.DateVal as StartDate, d2.DateVal  as EndDate
    from Dates d1 
    inner join Dates d2 on d1.DateVal < d2.DateVal 
    left join Dates d3 on d1.DateVal < d3.DateVal and 
    d3.DateVal < d2.DateVal where d3.DateVal is null

), QuantitiesSold as (
    select StartDate,EndDate,SUM(si.SoldItems) as Quantity
    from Periods p left join SoldItems si on p.StartDate < si.PeriodEnd and si.PeriodStart < p.EndDate
    group by StartDate,EndDate
)

select StartDate,EndDate, qs.Quantity
from QuantitiesSold qs
where qs.quantity is not null
```